# Custom Wordpress plugin issue with printing result

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a Wordpress plugin the issue is that, I am printing the posts according to the categories.

**I want a result like this:**

```
category 1
-------
post of category 1
second post of category 1

category 2
-------
post of category 2
second post of category 2
```

**But the result that I am getting is like this:**

```
post of category 1second post of category 1post of category 2second post of category 2
category 1
-------

category 2
-------
```

The posts are printing outside the category boxes.

**Here is my code:**

```
function show_opicle_cat()
{
    //database query
    $cats = get_categories($args); 

    // loop through the categries
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        // setup the cateogory ID
        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;

       // Make a header for the cateogry
       $pos .= "<div class='col-md-12' style='margin-bottom:2%;display:inherit !important;padding:0 !important;' ><div style='border:1px solid #cfcfcf !important;'>";
       $pos .= "<h6 style='background:#3b8b98!important;color:#fff;padding:10px;'>".ucwords($cat->name)." <a href='".get_category_link( $cat_id )."' class='pull-right' style='color:#fff !important;padding:0px 3px;bertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #fff;'>View All</a></h6><ul style='list-style-type:disc !important;'>";
       // create a custom wordpress query
       query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=$posts");
       // start the wordpress loop!
       if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
           // create our link now that the post is setup 
           $pos .="<li><img class='alignnone size-full wp-image-10424' src='newicon.gif' alt='' width='30' height='14'><a href='hii'>&nbsp;".ucwords(the_title())."</a></li>";
       endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category 
       $pos .="</ul></div></div>"; 
   } // done the foreach statement 
   return $pos;
}
```

Comment: What is "$pos" in this line of code 
"query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=$pos")" ?

Comment: @zipkundan seems like i am using same variable for 2 different things in line "query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=$pos")" $pos is basically number of posts i have change it with $posts. Now i m getting list bullet points of the posts inside the category box, but "ucwords(the_title())" is still printing outside the category boxes

Comment: Try changing "ucwords(the_title)" to "ucwords(get_the_tile())"